# How to identify members returning and or accepting the dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection, dnlib

Is there any possibility to figure out whether a return or argument type of a member is `dynamic`? The issue is that is compiles down to `System.Object`.

I've observed that if a member accepting arguments has a `dynamic` type present in its signature, an additional argument `A_0` will be added.

[image]

Are there any more tricks to figure out that a type is `dynamic` using reflection?

I'm using [**dnlib**](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) as my reflection library. The solution should work for all dotnet platforms; however, if it is limited to .NET Core, no biggie.

The project I'm working on is a Markdown documentation generator for C# libraries - you can find it [here](https://github.com/hailstorm75/MarkDoc.Core).

Thank you for any suggestions.

## Update

Identifying types that are not part of generic type arguments is simple.

If a return type is dynamic, then the method/property getter/property setter/delegate/event adder will have an additional argument in their signature called `A_0`.

If an argument is dynamic, then is will be decorated with a custom attribute: `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute`.

However, if the dynamic type is an argument of some generic type (`Dictionary<object, dynamic>`), then none of the generic argument types will be decorated with the custom attribute above. If the given generic type is returned by a member, then the additional argument will be present in the members signature. Same goes for if the generic type is an argument, it will be decorated with a custom attribute.

These indicators can be reliably used only if the generic type only either has only one argument or there is no other `object` type argument:

- `<object, dynamic>` **NOT OK**
- `<int, dynamic>` **OK**
- `<dynamic>` **OK**

Neither the additional argument nor the custom attribute indicates which generic argument is dynamic.

So far, I do not see a solution for this issue.

Comment: You already found the 'dynamic' attribute, did you try to use that?

Comment: @thehennyy The issue is that if I have a `public object MyMethod(dynamic arg)` or `public dynamic MyMethod(object arg)`, then both will be visible in reflection as `public object MyMethod(A_0, object arg)`. Therefore I have no way of identifying which one is of the dynamic type.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to use that in your refllection library but when you have a dynamic as return and object as parameter you have  `.param [0]` whereas when you have object as return and dynamic as parameter you have `.param [1]`